# why is there a GitHub folder on my computers boot drive?

Tags: github

I use GitHub. I thought the files were stored on the website. so why do I have a GitHub folder on my desktop (it takes up a lot of bootdrive space)? The GitHub folder has subfolders with the names of my repositories

C:\Users\cches\Documents\GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is choice made by the tool you are using when working with GitHub: you are using [`GitHub Desktop`](https://desktop.github.com/).

And GitHub Desktop chooses to store its local cloned repos in `%USERPROFILE%/Documents/GitHub` (as shown [in issue 1663](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1663))

You should be able to delete those stored repos, clone only the ones you need, and `File | Add existing repository` in Desktop, as in [issue 2851](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2851#issuecomment-331742449).